# Import hashed CSS className and select it in another file

Tags: css, webpack, hash, sass, css-selectors

I am using webpack to hash my css class names and for example I have:

```
checkbox.scss

input {
    .inner {
        // code
    }

    .checked {
        // code
    }
}
```

and I want to import this file as well as select the `.inner` class in my other file:

```
modal.scss

@import './checkbox';

.modal {
    &:hover {
        input + .inner:not(.checked)::after {
            // code..
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve such a manner of getting that `.inner` and `.checked` class from another file so that I could use them like that in another file? For now it seems my `modal.scss` file is generating new hashes for `.inner` and `.checked` therefore it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you referencing them in a global scss file with the checkbox scssfile first?

Comment: No, both of the files are separate, hashed on compilation and outside of global context. The classes are only accessible in components upon importing these files first

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, you must have a scss file that includes all the scss?

Comment: All of the scss are loaded in webpack, my project structure doesn't have a global scss file